# Spring STS | spring-mvc-showcase | 10 Errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm attempting to import the spring-mvc-showcase project from the list of example projects on the STS start page. It appears to import ok and creates the relevant project directories etc.

However, I then immediately get the following 10 errors display in the "Problems" view:

> - The project was not built since it depends on spring-mvc-showcase, which has build path errors
> - Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" form.jsp
> - Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" dataBinding.jsp
> - Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" fileupload.jsp
> - Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" redirectResults.jsp
> - Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/Lee/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/1.6.2/joda-time-1.6.2.jar' in project 'spring-mvc-showcase' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
> - Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" home.jsp    /spring-mvc-showcase/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views  line 1
> - Error occured processing XML 'Cannot find class [org.springframework.samples.mvc.data.custom.CustomArgumentResolver]'. See Error Log for more details   servlet-context.xml /spring-mvc-showcase/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet
> - Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" html.jsp    /spring-mvc-showcase/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/views
> - Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" viewName.jsp    /spring-mvc-showcase/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/views

I can create a new project from scratch which compiles and runs without a problem.

Obviously there is an issue somewhere, hopefully it's an issue specific to my environment as I can't imagine that the project intended to be the showcase for the framework has been made available without being tested.

Also it's worth mentioning that I'm using STS version 3.1.0.

Can anyone shed any light on these errors?

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This also looks a bit like your local Maven repository contains corrupted ZIP files. In that case I usually wipe out the .m2/repository directory entirely and let Maven download the artifacts again.

Comment: So do you mean I should just empty the m2/repository directory and restart STS?

Comment: I did what you suggested and was initially still getting the errors displaying. So I then deleted the "spring-mvc-showcase" project and -re-downloaded it. Now the errors have disappeared. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: not every time should i import ? is it a build problem using maven ?

Comment: @AtulD your question makes no sense

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve the same error without wiping out my Maven repository:

1. Right-click pom.xml. Select Run As | Maven install.
2. Right-click the project. Select Refresh.
3. From the top menu, select Project | Clean.

Answer (score 1):

mmm, are you sure that Maven work well?

Maybe Maven have not correctly dowloaded some dependencies used in the project.

Have you check if in the Maven m2 directory you have all the project need? (check if you have all the .jar files that you need)

If you are under a proxy you have to configure maven in its configuration file to use the proxy and only doing this thing you can download properly the dependencies that you need

Comment: To answer your question, the JAR which the compiler is complaining about (joda-time) does exist in the m2/repository directory.